# Prevent Typescript compilation when declared globals aren't in scope

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, global

Considering the following Node.js code that adds a function to the global object

```js
// sum.ts

declare global {
    function sum(a: number, b: number): number
}

function sum(a: number, b: number) {
    return a + b
}

global.sum = sum

export {}
```

Now, if another file imports `sum.ts`, the global function `sum` will be available

```js
// foo.ts

import 'sum.ts'

console.log(sum(2, 2)) // prints 4
```

However, in every file under the same `tsconfig`, `sum` will be available as a property of the global object, even if `sum.ts` haven't been imported, resulting in no errors at compile time. But at runtime, it will be a different story

```js
// bar.ts

console.log(sum(2, 2)) // prints ReferenceError: sum is not defined
```

How this behaviour can be stopped? It is easy to forget to import `sum.ts` when nothing warns you that the global function you used is not actually 'attached' to an actual function. The desired behaviour would be

```js
// bar.ts

console.log(sum(2, 2)) 
//          ~~~~~~~~~ <- Compilation error here because `sum.ts` haven't been imported.
```

Is it possible to achieve this? And why typescript doesn't make the declarations from `declare global` available only in files that actually import the declarations?

Comment: IMO the problem here is globals. If you just use modules properly, you wouldn't have this problem. It's *why* modules were created - so they can solve this kind of problem outside runtime. Adding globals has *always* been bad practice and modules have been fighting against for years before ES6 and TS introduced them officially.

Comment: Please elaborate why you think you DO need to use a global rather than a namespace (module). `global.foo = mysmelly.poo;` woops

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Imagine having like 20/30 functions that work on values and they have to be used by a library consumer like `{a: overwrite(10), b: increment(3), c: append('a', 'b'), d: moreFunctions(0)}`. Importing them globally avoids bloating the import section and keeps the code shorter when calling them.

Comment: "keeps the code shorter when calling them" so you are worrying about number of characters in the code? I would worry more about making the code clear to understand, robust and maintainable (which appears to be what you have currently encountered as an impediment)

Comment: this approach would be considerable if what I am asking in the question is achievable.

Comment: Wrong. If you have 20 to 30 *global values* that a bunch of unrelated functions manipulate, what you bloat is the cognitive complexity of the entire thing. Growing the functionality will inevitably make it exceptionally harder to reason about and properly handle. But yes, you get to save a few lines of code. So, you save, what, 30 seconds or so of writing code to every 30 minutes having to understand the code. Not a very good deal.

Comment: Keep in mind that globals are not typically garbage collected so you may encounter memory leaks or other challenges the more you use them.

Comment: I wasn't aware that globals cannot be garbage collected. But it is indeed obvious. I guess that I won't consider this approach anymore. The question still remains tho. Why did Typescript chose to support globals in such a weird way?

Comment: Only because JS already worked like this. Which is ***not*** good or sound design, mind you, but TS's goal is to be compatible with JS.